# Delete all ubuntu desktop stuff from ubuntu server

Tags: server, package-management

I have Ubuntu server VPS, I installed 3 months ago some packages to try to get a remote connection, without success. Anyway, now I'm cleaning some stuff from my server, the problem is that I found a lot of usefulness packages like Firefox, Thunderbird, ubuntu-wallpapers, unity 2-d, etc ... My question is, is there anyway to safe clean those packages that are related to ubuntu desktop version? Perhaps that there is some "magic" command.
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: How did you get Ubuntu Desktop packages on a server?

Comment: @Rolandixor: I think that I installed ubuntu dekstop packages, it's 3 months ago, so I can't remember exactly the command. As I've seen I think that I have to delete every package manually :/, but it'll not be 100% "clean" . Any suggestion please?

Comment: If you are not running anything on the server as yet, I would suggest just starting over. You'll have a lot of packages to remove and it won't be easy to mark all those that should be removed and preserve what shouldn't.

Comment: @RolandiXor: The problem is that I have a lot of stuff in production in the server. So it's better to keep those packages in disk and forget about cleaning it :/. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following command sequence removes the `ubuntu-desktop` metapackage and then all automatically installed, unneeded packages (i. e. nothing depends on them anymore).

```
apt-get remove ubuntu-desktop
apt-get autoremove
```

If `autoremove` doesn't do anything, then somehow all the dependencies of `ubuntu-desktop` are not flagged as “installed automatically”, which is required for `autoremove` to select them. You could set this flag for every recursive dependency (manually or with a script), but I don't think it's worth the work, if you don't experience problems related to desktop packages.

Comment: I executed that command, and the size of ubuntu-desktop is almost 100kb! So I think that it's not related with other desktop packages.

Comment: It's just a metapackage that depends on various other packages. The second command should remove the latter.

Comment: I executed the second command and it's saying nothing to remove :/ .

Comment: It removed a lot of stuff here, but after a reboot, I still see the desktop login. I can login, but the desktop is empty. Any idea how to to get rid of these remainings?

Comment: @not2savvy Could you please open a [new question](/questions/ask) if you have a new or follow-up question? The comment section is not suited or meant for new questions or extended discussion. You’re welcome to send me a comment with a notification to draw my attention to it. Thanks.